# Is "But, I later realized, have no car" grammatical?

Tags: commas, pronouns

I was engaged in some informal but I hope grammatical conversation with a friend who is less fluent in English than me (so I didn't want to confuse them!). It went:

> - So why are you so upset?
> - You really want to know?
> - Sure!
> - Well, you know how I was telling you how I sold my car?
> - Yeah
> - I was excited about driving up to Manchester...
> - OK.
> - But, I later realized, have no car.

Is "But, I later realized, have no car" grammatical?

I think maybe, and with the following reason.

"But, I later realized, have no car"? sounds better than "But I later realized, have no car". I think the former sounds better due to the grammar, and one answer for why that is, is that it's grammatical (rather than, say, more rhetorical or I'm not interested in their reply).

---

I am concerned with the elided "I" in what would be the independent clause "have no car", and so I'm *guessing* it may be grammatical because in the latter the phrase "I later realized" is parenthesized (so that the conditional conjunction 'but' belongs to the independent clause "[I] have no car"), if that's not a misunderstanding.

Or perhaps it's because the conjunction 'but' in the former, used, example need not be read as set off with a comma.

---

The question *seems* a difficult one, as wikipedia says:

> the [dropping of pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language#English) is generally restricted to very informal
>   speech and certain fixed expressions, and the rules for their use are
>   complex and vary among dialects and register

I would be asking for BrSE, at least foremostly.

Comment: you can't elide the i

Comment: well, if you can prove it, then sure @Toothrot it seems alright to me as speech

Comment: i don't think this question should be downvoted. it's clear, and i just won't easily find the answer. the voter seems to act like a *meta* voter, i.e. voting down because they disagree with something said in the question. that, imho, debases the use of the site, as well as being a misuse of it

Comment: obviously examples with this structure *will* exist, it's that generic a question @choster so asking for examples of it is trivial, even if it is grammatically incorrect. i would have believed (see my new meta question) that questions on elu which explicitly allow answers explaining why something is ungrammatical **should** be tolerated, and answered

Comment: my mistake @choster i have edited the question to include "explicit" reference to the possibility both are in (grammatically) incorrect. perhaps now the voter can retract their vote?

Comment: now there's a close vote. how awful! i think whoever is voting really *should* take this issue to meta, though obviously not doing so, itself, is not misuse of the site!

Comment: another issue is that, because i *suspect* that the question is being voted to close for reasons of clarity, rather than e.g. being a useful question, i am stuck trying to clarify a question completely unsure what's unclear about it. i think this question needs some attention, now, and not just because i want the question answered (see my meta post about this)

Comment: oh i see now it's been voted as off-topic. i fail to see **anything** off-topic about it!

Comment: You are asking "why does A sound better than B?" when to me, they both sound ungrammatical, and neither is particularly better. So it seems really a matter of opinion.

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't follow @PeterShor it's no more a "matter of opinion" than any questions which are difficult to answer for experts (see the quote i edited in) and i have now **explicitly** asked a question that can be answered *even if both the example statements are ungrammatical* (which now two people claim without proof or an answer)

Comment: Why does lemon cake seem better than strawberry ice cream? This answer is a matter of opinion, because it only seems better ***to me***.

Comment: i'm not asking for your opinion on cake (or icecream) i'm simply asking for what grammarians say about cake (and icecream): whether or not it is grammatical @PeterShor (as well as whether the icecream is). i'll edit in the question, as i think the phrase "why does it sound better" has confused the users here into thinking it's not about grammar!

Comment: Your question requires more context if it's to sound idiomatic.  In the stark way you present it, neither version sounds natural. At a push, a sympathetic and interested native speaker (e.g. NOT Basil Fawlty) would probably be able to understand even if precisely *who* has no car can only be ambiguous.

Comment: ah interesting. what sort of context would it need? @Dan perhaps a discussion / narrative in which the sentence explains something?

Comment: Please clarify *who* has no car.

Comment: Context might make it easier to understand the idiosyncratic style and so make your meaning clear.

Comment: My best guess is that the subject-less "*...have no car"* is part of an internal stream-of-consciousness monologue

Comment: (Just woken up)... "Must rush.  Train's in 10 minutes. Hungry. Eat something. Lost my bag.  Oh yes, left it in car.  Have no car!! Must have been given a lift home after party... *etc*"

Comment: sure. but really i just want an answer which says why pro-drop is un/suitable there, rather than why it *seems* OK @Dan !

Comment: Dropping pronoun is problematic because it makes unclear *who* has no car.

Comment: wow ok. how odd that it's "unclear", rather than just unclear as to whether it's grammatical ( :-) ) that's cleared up why it's ungrammatical, but not whether anyone would say it *is* grammatical. perhaps an answer would help the latter!

Comment: Your re-edited question, explaining why you have left out the pronoun, provides helpful context (although still unclear *who* has no car)

Comment: good one, thanks @Dan

Comment: Your title and text are confusing as to what exactly your question really is. If your question is "Is this sentence correct?' say that explicitly in your text.

Comment: ok i may need to simplify the question @Mitch thanks for the comment!

Comment: (note that with edge cases like this one there will be a lot of variability in what is considered acceptable, almost by definition)

Comment: No,    it's just not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I was excited about driving up to Manchester...
>
> OK.
>
> But, I later realized, have no car.

If we consider only the last line then, after removing the "parenthetical clause", we get "But have no car."  This is clearly non-grammatical (though comprehensible).

However, if we consider the first line, and regard the two lines as simply being a single (though disjointed) sentence, we get "I was excited about driving up to Manchester but have no car."  This is valid syntax and semantics.

Often in speech a perfectly valid sentence can get disjointed in this fashion, especially when the listener interjects an "OK" or some such to acknowledge his comprehension.  Within reason this doesn't affect the validity of the overall statement.

Comment: thank you for your answer, which, along with dan's comment, *was* helpful... i am still concerned that the your claim "is clearly non-grammatical" cites no-one. but feel that my question is answered now.

Comment: and thanks for noticing how the interjection was working!!

Answer (score 2):

I am willing to bet you imagined something like below but didn't type it out as such because is quite esoteric outside of [train-of-thought writing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/142083259X) (disclaimer: I am including the book here merely as an example):

> "But I -- I later realized -- have no car."

There should be 2 "I"s; it is a interjected independent clause, the subject does not carry over.

Comment: no, not at all! see my edit. anyway, you didn't address my use of 'pro-drop', so i'm concerned that your answer isn't even an answer to my question (which must still be unclear?)

Answer (score 1):

Why does it seem okay with the comma, but not without? When you have two parallel clauses with the same subject, you can drop the subject from the second one.

> I had a book I was reading, but left it on the airplane.
>   I was excited about driving up to Manchester, but have no car.

When you add an interjection, it's still grammatical.

> I was excited about driving up to Manchester but, I later realized, have no car.

Now, in dialog, when somebody interrupts that sentence, you still might be able to argue that it's grammatical:

> I was excited about driving up to Manchester ...
>   OK
>   ... but, I later realized, have no car.

On the other hand, if you have a main clause and a dependent clause with the same subject, you cannot leave the subject off the dependent clause. The following are ungrammatical. (Asterisks indicate ungrammaticality.)

> *I told him would drive him home.
>   *I realized have no car.

So if *I later realized* is not an interjection (which it isn't unless you put a comma after the *but*), the whole thing is ungrammatical:

> *I was excited about driving up to Manchester, but I later realized, have no car.

Without the first part of the interrupted sentence, *"I was excited about driving up to Manchester,"* the second half of the interrupted sentence, *"but, I realized, have no car"* is ungrammatical whether or not there is a comma after the *but*.

Answer (score 0):

> [The dropping of subject pronouns](https://www.isle-linguistics.org/assets/content/documents/hogg/weir2009.pdf) in spoken English is analysed as a
>   phonological phenomenon, following work by Gerken (1991);
>   specifically, that the first syllable in an intonational phrase, if
>   unstressed, can be deleted in English

'I have no car' can be analyzed as a separate intonational phrase, dependent on what is meant. There's a difference between

- I later realized | I have no car

and

- I later realized I have no car

The former intonation suggests I still have no car. Because the "I" is not stressed (the speaker is not emphasizing that they rather than someone else lack a car) in spoken English you can use pro-drop there.

---

In writing it would be an example of "diary drop" (the dropping of subject pronouns in informal written English, common in diaries), which some claim is permitted if the dropped pronoun (I) is the "[topic](https://awweir.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/weir-ug-diss.pdf)" of the sentence, which it is here (the topic is myself).

Comment: Best explain what is a "diary drop" to users/learners, I have no idea what it is myself.

Comment: Worth emphasizing that no native English speaker would consider "I later realized have no car" to be grammatical, no matter how many commas are added! It just sounds completely wrong.

I think it fails for the same reason as Weir's (ungrammatical) example 9b: "When I was in Paris, (e) visited the Louvre.", from the paper you linked. 


For the benefit of any English learners here: *avoid dropped pronouns* - it's intensely colloquial, and slightly sloppy. It'll make you sound like you don't know basic sentence construction!

Comment: You don't ever drop pronouns? I find that hard to believe @SusanW

Comment: @user3293056 I do, oh yes. Do you mean about how I'm advising people to avoid them?